# How to use ckEditor in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4, ckeditor

I am very new to Laravel framework and I want to use CKEdiotor in Laravel4 but I don't know how to use it and how to install it. Anyone please help me.

Comment: don't know how to google either, must be tough being you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ckeditor package for laravel 4 is [here](https://github.com/devhook/ckeditor)

That package looks like it makes it easy to be downloaded to the vendor directory. You'd the publish the asserts and still what was mentioned above.

I have no idea If that package stays current with the original source or not.
Also, I don't see thy much difference between that package and following the instructions on the Ckeditor site.

For a trial, make a view (template) like you normally would and then follow the instructions on the Ckeditor site. It should work with no problems. The biggest issue is just cleaning up paths and such.